# What types of prototypes exist in C?

Tags: c, prototype

Well, i read somewhere (i dont remember where) that are like types of prototypes in C. Ones used to sending parameters and others used for data return. What are those named and what are those used for ?

Comment: Didn't you just list what they were used for?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  Please go and find where you read about them again.  There are prototype declarations for functions, which should usually be in a header (unless the function is `static` —ignoring `inline` pro tem).  And there are prototype definitions of functions, and all functions you write (or encounter) should use the prototype rotation.

Comment: There can be an infinite number of function prototype implementations.  There are much fewer function _argument parameter_ types

Comment: @ryyker **`There can be an infinite number of function prototype implementations`** implementation is only one `type funcname([void] | [type] [,another types]);`** . possible prototypes number  is very large but for sure finite (limited by for example by the disc size - files have to be store somewhere) and max number of function parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"...Ones used to sending parameters and others used for data return...."*

Using common terms, you may be referring to function parameter types, in particular as they have to do with *input* parameter and *output* parameter.

In actuality, `C` does not distinguish or define *input* and *output* function parameters per se.  By definition `C` has only *pass by value* function parameters.  However, the *type* of value that is passed can be one of two distinct categories: either the *value* represented by the object itself, or the *value* of the address of the object.  If it is the value of the object itself that is passed, then the called function is not able to modify that value.  If however the value of the *address of* the object is passed, then the function is able to modify the value of the object residing at that address, and upon function return, the updated value of the object is accessible via the return function parameter.

So, to simplify wording for this illustration, and in the context of this answer the following terms are used:

- *input* - function parameter that passes value of object.
- *output* - function parameter that passes the value of the address of the object and provides access to updated object value upon return.

To illustrate, with respect to *input* and *output* the following prototype has both.  The first two arguments are *input*, and the third is *output*.:

```
void func1(int val1, int val2, int *sum)
{
    *sum = val1 + val2;
}

called like this: 

int a = 100;
int b = 300;
int sum = 0;

int return = func1(a, b, &sum);//value of sum == 400 upon return
```

Comment: it is called side effect - not output. It is not C#. using this terminology all is input, the second one has just another type

Comment: What about this one? Is it in, out or inout :) https://godbolt.org/z/ToMaq8

Comment: @P__J__ - That was a typo and is fixed.

Comment: @P__J__ -  Updated to address using output and output for the context of this answer only, recognizing that those terms are not explicitly used to define parameter types in C.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one type of function prototype. Using the function prototype  you tell the compiler what is the type of return value of the function and how many and what type arguments are.

Historically functions can have default type of arguments and  default type of the return value. The default type is `int`

Comment: Funny!  I came up with two types.  However, we are more in agreement than disagreement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  I think that we can call `extern` variable declarations  "variable protype" as well :)